# FB Logout with C# sdk

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, sdk, logout

I'm logged in to my app using my FB credentials. In the end I do a logout and remove my session variables. I'm logged out from application, but the FB session remains open although I do a post to the FB logout page with the post like in the code:

```
if (Session["FBAccessToken"] != null){

  var fb = new Facebook.FacebookClient();
  string accessToken = Session["FBAccessToken"] as string;
  //var logoutUrl = fb.GetLogoutUrl(new { access_token = accessToken, next = "https://www.facebook.com/", });
  var logoutUrl = fb.GetLogoutUrl(new {  next = "https://www.facebook.com/", });

  fb.Post(logoutUrl.AbsoluteUri, new { access_token = accessToken });
  Session.RemoveAll();
}
```

I've tried both: logoutUrl generated with and without access token parameter, neither worked for me.

Comment: hi check this article : http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Logout.aspx

Comment: Already checked that Pranay, can't find anything helpful, I don't have FacebookOAuthClient() class only FacebookClient() class

Comment: Do you suggest that everything is ok with the code but the FB bug is taking place?

Comment: if yout have dll with FacebookClient.FacebookClient you have FacebookClient.FacebookOAuthClient as well - try to find it.

Comment: Ionly have a dll named Facebook.dll and it only has Facebook.FacebookClient class but not FacebookClient.FacebookOAuthClient

Comment: @Biljanka - So use the oAuth SDK instead.  Although I was able to find that class contained within that reference dll with no problem.

Comment: I use FB 6.0.24 SDK source to build the Facebook.dll but there is no FacebookOAutClient class there.

Comment: Really stuck on this one. Answer pls.

Comment: @Biljanka FacebookOAuthClient was present in v5. it has been removed in v6.

Comment: @prabir So, how should I handle this in v6?

Comment: @Biljanka did u check my answer yet? i posted it as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 2):

There has been changes on facebook logout since my last blog post. Here is the way to logout.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
var logoutUrl = fb.GetLogoutUrl(new {access_token = "...", next = "...." });

// redirect to logoutUrl.AbsoluteUri
```

next url cannot be any arbitrary url. I has to be the one that is part of the site url which you used to retrieve the access token.

Comment: It's all teh same result if I put my start page or callback page in the nex parameter, the fb user session is still active, when you open facebook.com

Comment: solved it. my mistake was that I was doing a post and not redirect to the logout url.

Comment: what if the user doesn't have access token yet? what if he pressed "Skip" button or pressed x mark of the window? (which means user canceled during oauth process)  Should I just leave the access_token as blank?

Answer (score 0):

@prabir has the answer. Here is a complete answer after I tweaked it for my MVC app. Just replace "localhost:51042/" with whatever URL is appropriate for your app.

This actually fills a hole in the tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        WebSecurity.Logout();

        if (Session["facebooktoken"] != null)
        {
            var fb = new Facebook.FacebookClient();
            var logoutUrl = fb.GetLogoutUrl(new { access_token = Session["facebooktoken"], next = "http://localhost:51042/" });

            Response.Redirect(logoutUrl.AbsoluteUri);
            Session.RemoveAll();
        } 

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```